# antlr add syntactic predicate

Tags: antlr

For the following rule :

```
 switchBlockLabels

:   ^(SWITCH_BLOCK_LABEL_LIST switchCaseLabel* switchDefaultLabel? switchCaseLabel*)
;
```

I got an error:"rule switchBlockLabels has non-LL descision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2".And I tried to add syntactic predicate to solve this problem.I read the book "The Definitive ANTLR Reference".And Now I am confused that since there is no alternatives in rule switchBlockLabels,then no decision need to be made on which one to choose.
Is anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the tree parser stumbles upon, say, 2 `switchCaseLabel`s (and no `switchDefaultLabel` in the middle), it does not know to which these `switchCaseLabel`s belong. There are 3 possibilities the parser can choose from:

- 2 `switchCaseLabel`s are matched by the 1<sup>st</sup> `switchCaseLabel*`;
- 2 `switchCaseLabel`s are matched by the 2<sup>nd</sup> `switchCaseLabel*`;
- 1 `switchCaseLabel` is matched by the 1<sup>st</sup> `switchCaseLabel*`, and one by the 2<sup>nd</sup> `switchCaseLabel*`.

and since the parser does not like to choose for you, it emits an error.

You need to do something like this instead:

```
switchBlockLabels
 : ^(SWITCH_BLOCK_LABEL_LIST switchCaseLabel* (switchDefaultLabel switchCaseLabel*)?)
 ;
```

That way, when there are only `switchCaseLabel`s, and no `switchDefaultLabel`, these `switchCaseLabel`s would be always matched by the first `switchCaseLabel*`: there is no ambiguity anymore.